# Can't SSH into Debian instance after assigning static IP

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I have a device that posts telemetry data to a remote server. The device runs Debian and up until now I've been debugging it by SSH'ing in over my local network via WiFi. In the field, the device will use a 4G modem, and I've had my ISP assign static IPs the devices for remote troubleshooting. The 4G modem is working to connect to the internet -- I can ping websites, etc. -- but I get a timeout every time I attempt to connect via SSH to the static IP. I'm sure I've misconfigured either /etc/dhcpcd.conf or /etc/network/interfaces, but I'm not sure which. The interface is `eth1`.

ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:ff:13:77:70  
          inet addr:166.123.123.123  Bcast:166.123.123.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::deef:4034:ff93:d78/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5310 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:21669 (21.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:4d:e4:26  
          inet addr:10.0.1.90  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::29c6:be79:e368:d066/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21633 errors:0 dropped:14440 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3120767 (2.9 MiB)  TX bytes:259096 (253.0 KiB)
```

/etc/network/interfaces (/etc/network/interfaces.d is empty)

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option ntp_servers
#option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
nohook lookup-hostname
```

Routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         123.sub-166-123 0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
default         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
166.123.123.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth1
my.usb          123.sub-166-123 255.255.255.255 UGH   204    0        0 eth1
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: @kaylum Done, apologies.

Comment: I don't see any configuration of eth1 in /etc/networks/interface. It is also useful to have the route table.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I've added the route table. You are correct--there is no config of eth1 in /etc/networks/interfaces. The 4G modem is a USB modem; when it's plugged in it just "shows up" in ifconfig and route. I haven't touched the interfaces file yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included for posterity if anyone finds this on Google:

The issue had nothing to do with networking configuration on the box; in the last two months, Verizon enacted a policy to block incoming connections to M2M devices. If you need remote access to a device over a cellular connection, you will need to work with Verizon to set up a private network.